# AngularJS MVC how to load a page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to construct a "click and read" AngularJS website. I have a header that works that takes the user between a directory, contact page and the home page. That works fine. My question is:
How do I code this so that from the Home page the user can click a button or link that will take him/her to page2 then from page 2 another click will take them to page 3 and so on? I would also like them to be able to move the other direction as well.

Here is my file/folder structure:

```
app/app.js
app/lib

content/css/styles.css

header.html
index.html

views/contactMe.html
views/directory.html
views/home.html
views/page1.html
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/directory', {
            templateUrl: 'views/directory.html',
            //since this page requires a controller
            controller: 'myController'
        })
        .when('/contactMe', {
            templateUrl: 'views/contactMe.html',
            //since this page requires a controller
            controller: 'myController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });

}]);  //.config


angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.message = ("Hello World");
}
});
```

header.html

```
<div id="menu-bar">
    <h1>My Sample App</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#directory">Directory</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contactMe">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>Sample app</title>
    <link href="content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>
    <main ng-view></main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in each page button to go back: `<a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>` and also button to go to next page (if you do not have a lot of pages, you can do it manually) - `<a href="#page1">Go to page1</a>`

Here is my example:

```
<div id="menu-bar">
    <h1>Header</h1>
          <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#directory">Directory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contactMe">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    Body
    <div ng-view=""></div>
```

home.html:

```
<a style="float:right"  href="#page1">Go to page1</a>

<a style="float:left"  href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>
<br />
<div style="text-align:center">home</div>
```

working plunker: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/1cBb8TzSX5mDJy4v

EDIT: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Gm0TkOZCIxwxDerQ

Comment: I want to keep my existing header. Can I use your answer if I do not incorporate your header code? Thank you.

Comment: @JohnM. Of course you can keep your existing header, check out edit